# Why does PCA on high-dimensional text data improve the performance of random forest but not a decision tree classifier?

Tags: classification, pca, random-forest, natural-language

Why does PCA on high-dimensional text data improve the performance of random forest but not a decision tree classifier?

I am dealing with high dimensional text data.
I found that performing PCA to an optimised number of dimensions (obtained using grid search) improved the performance of a random forest classifier. Applying the same to a decision tree classifier had no impact on results.

Comment: This is not a universal property and it is to a large extent dataset dependent.

Comment: So there is no generic reason why PCA improves the performance of the random forest classifier but not the decision tree classifier ?

Comment: For neither of the two.